# Removing borders from AvalonDock panel

Tags: c#, xaml, styles, avalondock

here is whats getting on my nerve:

My job si to restyle application, so i didn’t wrote it, i have to slightly change the code(.cs or .xaml). Problem lies within avalonDock…i cant remove borders from panels, or change its color.

This is part of code, where dockingManager parts are defined(lets call it MainView.xaml)

```
<ad:DockingManager Name="dockingManager" >
        <ad:ResizingPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ad:DockablePane ad:ResizingPanel.ResizeWidth="50" Name="navigatorHostCtrlPane" >
                <ad:DockableContent Name="navigatorHostCtrl" Title="{StaticResource Navi}" IsCloseable="False" Background="Transparent"/>
            </ad:DockablePane>
            <ad:ResizingPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <ad:DockablePane Name="mainPane" >
                    <ad:DockableContent x:Name="mainHostCtrl" Title="{StaticResource Sc}" AllowDrop="False" IsCloseable="False" ClipToBounds="False" Background="White"/>
                </ad:DockablePane>
                <ad:DockablePane ad:ResizingPanel.ResizeHeight="250"  >
                    <ad:DockableContent Name="dataHostCtrl" Title="{StaticResource Dt}" IsCloseable="False" Background="White"/>
                </ad:DockablePane>
            </ad:ResizingPanel>
        </ad:ResizingPanel>
    </ad:DockingManager>
```

And this is where parts are set in .cs file(MainView.xaml.cs) like this:

```
BindRegionToGui(regionManager, RegionNames.NavigatorRegion, navigatorHostCtrl);
```

And BindRegionToGui():

```
private static void BindRegionToGui(IRegionManager regionManager, string regionName, UIElement content)
    {
        var reg = (AvalonDockRegion)regionManager.Regions[regionName];
        reg.Bind(content);
    }
```

I cant change style of outer border even in element by setting BorderThickness = “1“, or in style definition:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ad:DockablePane}" TargetType="{x:Type ad:DockablePane}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property=“BorderThickness“ Value=“0“/>
</Style>
```

I can alter whole dockingPanes by setting style like this(after some example):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ad:DockablePane}">
       …
    <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ad:DockablePane}">
                    <Border  
                        Background=….
             </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But with this – the content won’t show up. I assume, that content.template overrides it, but i dont know how i can put application’s defined panels into it.

Sorry if this is stupid question but i am really beginner in xaml / c# so i’m in kind of a bad situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I restyled AvalonDock in pretty dumb way. I've downloaded source code from http://avalondock.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets, changed generic.xaml and rebuild whole library.

Comment: This does not answer the question